# Search Count Wordpress Theme

Tags: count, code

I have a code that displays results for search but, I need it to include the count
not just keyword searched

```
<h1 class="font-thin h2 m-b">
<?php 
printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', 'musik' ), '<span class="font-bold">' . get_search_query() . '</span>' );

 ?>
</h1>
```

Comment: And what would you like to see instead?

Comment: i would like to see the number of search results found

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the search results template then you can find out the count by using the below code.

```
global $wp_query;
$count =  $wp_query->found_posts
```

variable `$count` contains the count of post against the search.

Answer (score 0):

Please open and modify this line in `search.php`.

```
<h1 class="font-thin h2 m-b">
Search Result for <?php 
/* Search Count */ $allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); 
$key = wp_specialchars($s, 1); 
$count = $allsearch->post_count; _e(''); _e('<span class="search-terms">'); 
echo $key; _e('</span>'); _e(' &mdash; '); 
echo $count . ' '; _e('articles'); 
wp_reset_query(); 

?>

</h2>
```

[Reference link](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/display-search-term-and-result-count-in-wordpress/)